# Session regenerate causes expired session with fast AJAX calls

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

My application is a full AJAX web page using Codeigniter Framework and memcached session handler.

Sometimes, it sends a lot of asynchronous calls and if session has to regenerate its ID (to avoid session fixation security issue), the session cookie is not renewed fast enough and some AJAX calls fail due to session id expired.

Here is a schematic picture I made to show clearly the problem :
[image]

I walked across the similar threads (for example [this one](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/154)) but the answers doesn't really solve my problem, I can't disable the security as there is only AJAX calls in my application.

Nevertheless, I have an Idea and I would like an opinion before hacking into the Codeigniter session handler classes :
The idea is to manage 2 simultaneous session Ids for a while, for example 30 seconds. This would be a maximum request execution time. Therefore, after session regeneration, the server would still accept the previous session ID, and switch to session to the new one.
Using the same picture that would give something like this :

[image]

Comment: What version of CI are you using? This seems like an ongoing bug in CI session handling, particularly with db sessions. I think supporting multiple session IDs may work as a hack, but seems like it's asking for trouble. Can you use some other session handler, perhaps native PHP sessions with Redis or similar? Also did you look at [this thread](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3097)?

Comment: @Idg : I read all these threads yes. It speak about the problem and CI3 (my version) solved it by disabling session renewing with AJAX requests. The problem is I *only* have AJAX requests in my app....

Comment: @NicolasThery Can you simply  explain what kind of issue you having

Comment: @Abdulla The schemas I made are so complex ? A first requests gets a new session Id (Session Id Regeneration) and the second one, an asynchronous request which is ran before the first response does not have the new session ID. The servers rejects it.

Comment: is all session names are same ??

Comment: There are two solutions. Close session as soon as the ajax call is made and queue ajax calls so they are not fired async. Else likes look at server sent and service workers to handle some of the queries. At regenerate check if session is active (session_status() == 2).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your proposed solution is quite reasonable. In fact, [the people at OSWAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Renewal_Timeout) advise just that:

> The web application can implement an additional renewal timeout after which the session ID is automatically renewed. (...) The previous session ID value would still be valid for some time,
>   accommodating a safety interval, before the client is aware of the new
>   ID and starts using it. At that time, when the client switches to the
>   new ID inside the current session, the application invalidates the
>   previous ID.

Unfortunately this cannot be implemented with PHP's standard session management (or I don't know how to do that). Nevertheless, implementing this behaviour in [a custom session driver](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#custom-drivers) <sup>1</sup> should not pose any serious problem.

I am now going to make a bold statement: the whole idea of regenerating the session ID periodically, is broken. Now don't get me wrong, regenerating the session ID on login (or more accurately, [as OSWAP put it](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Renew_the_Session_ID_After_Any_Privilege_Level_Change), on "privilege level change") is indeed a very good defense against [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).

But regenerating session IDs *regularly* poses more problems than it solves: during the interval when the two sessions co-exist, they must be synchronised or else one runs the risk loosing information from the expiring session.

There are better (and easier) defenses against simple session theft: use SSL (HTTPS). Periodic session renewal should be regarded as [the poor man's workaround](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/1250) to this attack vector.

---

<sup>1</sup> [link to the standard PHP way](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Comment: I really like you're answer because you searched for OWASP statements which is a security referential I really rely on. 
However, HTTPS is not enough, many companies have breaches in their SSL decryption/encryptions, making internal hacking white boxed.
A strong security is a security with many barriers.

At the moment, I will rely on the memcached session garbage collector and use the "don't destroy sessions on renewing" feature. This is not optimal but still it will be beter than nothing.

Comment: I am not quite sure of what threat model you are defending against. If you are worried of an attack exploiting a poor SSL implementation, then fix it in priority because any other defense becomes meaningless if this is compromised. If you are worried of an inside job, then I believe periodic session regeneration will not help at all.

Comment: MANY big companies have an applicative firewall that blocks some kind of flows, Lets take VOIP for example. To do that, they have a front proxy with which an application creates a SSL handshake, the SSL connection is NOT done on the full way to the user. (I am this application, and I am not able to handle all my users infrastructure, I am a cloud service software) 
After that, this proxy reads the network packet and do his job, detecting all its rules. THEN is starts a new handshake with the employee user using an internal certificate : THIS certificate can be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

your problem seems to be less with the actual speed of the requests (though it is a contributing factor) but more with concurrency.
If i understand right, your javascript application makes many (async) ajax calls - fast (presumably in bursts)- and sometimes some of them fail due to session invalidation due to what you think is speed of requests issue.
Well i think that the problem is that you actually have several concurrent requests to the server, while the first one has its session renewed the other essentially cannot see it because the request is already made and waits to be processed by the server.

This problem will of course manifest itself only when doing several requests for the same user simultaneously.

Now The real question here - what in your application business logic demands for this?

It looks to me that you are trying to find a technical solution to a 'business' problem. What i mean is that either you've mis-interpreted your requirements, or the requirements are just not that well thought/specified.

I would advice you to try some of the following:

- ask yourself if these multiple simultaneous requests can be combined to one
- look deeply into the requirements and try to find the real reason why you do what you do, maybe there is no real business reason for this
- every time before you fire the series of requests fire a 'refresh' ajax request to get the new session, and only on success proceed with all the other requests

Hope some of what i've wrote help to guide you to solution.
Good luck

Comment: Given the amount of people with a similar problem, I don't think "change your business logic" is ultimately going to be the answer. I agree that there might be some business logic improvements, but there also seems to be a real CodeIgniter technical problem here. Using promise chains on the FE could also be helpful and hits both sides (tech and logic), but again, won't completely solve the problem.

Comment: hi, I am trying to guide to try and think differently about your problem. But I did suggested two technical ways to mitigate it. The implementation is up to you of course. Anyway I still intuitively feel that firing many concurrent Ajax calls for the same user is a strange thing and can, and should be avoided.       So yes, I still would say you probably solving the wrong problem.  Maybe you could describe the use case here to give context and then maybe I'll see that I am wrong and could help you better?

Comment: @VladLyga First : Thank you for your answers. As Idg said, the problem may occur during different business cases. I described a burst use case that I *can* transform to a grouped request (It will also be better for network troughput,  performances and reliability). But the problem may occur in a much more simpler (and not alterable) use case : Lets say I have a refresh counter that runs every minute, If I run another asynchronous request at the same time, at the time of session regeneration, the first request regenerates the session and the second get kicked and throws the authenticate popup.

Comment: @Idg : Can you explain or link me to "promise chains on the FE", I dont know about it. BTW I will check the first link you sent to me

Comment: Promise chains : http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/
This is not an option : My requests are sent from different parts of code, I cant chain them easily

Comment: @NicolasThery I personally wouldn't implement the hack you proposed for CI. But if you are determined to 'patch' it in any case on server side, i would implement it as a 'leeway'. Meaning that if a request with expired session is made within, say, 1 minute of expiration, then let this request through anyway.  Or just opt for the much simpler client side 'fix' - create a wrapper around the ajax call to check for session expiration, then all your ajax calls should go through this one function, and it will take care of handling the session refresh.